# Xmail shows error at Gmail

Tags: email, email-server, gmail, mx-record

Hello I am using Xmail server at IP 65.75.241.26 hosted at www.softmail.me using which I can send and receive email to/from all email service providers but unable to receive back from Gmail. This error lies only with Gmail.

Experts says that Gmail requires proper working MX records where as for other emailing providers do not bother much. Is MX records the solution for my problem? Or is there any other issue?

My mailserver outgoing at softmail.me:25
My mailserver incoming at softmail.me:110

Please help me how to get rid of this issue.

Comment: In Gmail my mails are not being spammed. But in case of Hotmail my mails are being spammed.

Answer (score 0):

For hotmail you need to contact them at http://mail.live.com/mail/policies.aspx .  For Gmail you would need to contact them at https://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=81126